# Aesthetically pleasing GUI components

Tags: user-interface

I want to make my GUI components aesthetically pleasing.

Is there any particular ratio I should use between a component's width and height that would make it look especially pleasing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) maybe? ;) It's been used in art and architecture for thousands of years.

Comment: @Martinho: That answer is hard to dispute. ;)

Comment: @somebody: I know, I was about to post it myself :(

Comment: Not to mention, you know, biology and physics.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome is pretty pleasing to look at.  It seems like the latest trend is to use big, soft-looking buttons with cartoony icons.  Also controls like text boxes, etc. should be large with rounded corners, and there shouldn't be too many of them.

Comment: This is very subjective - to me, Chrome is actually rather ugly!  But to each their own.

Comment: Very true...  I happen to like Chrome, but I could see why someone wouldn't.

Comment: Since when is Chrome a standard for GUI Aesthetics?

Comment: since www.google.com became one of the best looking websites in existence.

Comment: You people probably think Bing is where it's at...  j/k